# How to get the Text inside HTML <p> (paragraph) element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is the HTML snippet for a radio button. I want to get the 'Select from list' using selenium Webdriver.Unable to fetch using getText()

```
 <p> <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="selectedItem"> Select By Audit ID </p>
 <p> <input type="radio" value="2" name="selectedItem"> Select from list of My Open Audits </p>
 <p> <input type="radio" value="3" name="selectedItem"> Select from list of All Open Audits </p>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML snippet properly. It's not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the element based off of the `input` then use the following `xpath` and then `getText()`

```
//input[@name='selectedItem']/..
```

**Edit**

```
//input[@name='selectedItem'][@value='1']/..
```

Comment: Below is the code I used but i am getting empty value                                      @FindBy(css="input[value='1'][name='selectedItem']")
 private WebElement SelectAuditIDOption;                                                      SelectAuditIDOption.getText();

Comment: @user1882624 not css. I provided you `xpath`

Comment: @user1882624 I got it. Actually should be `@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='selectedItem']/..")
private WebElement SelectAuditIDOption;`

Comment: Sorry for not providing complete info. this is my complete Radio button option   `<p>
<input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1"     name="selectedItem">
Select By Audit ID
</p>
<br>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="selectedItem">
Select from list of My Open Audits
</p>
<br>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="selectedItem">
Select from list of All Open Audits
</p>`

Comment: Add an extra attribute `//input[@name='selectedItem'][@value='1']/..` [@value='1'] for first <p>. Increment the number as needed

Comment: I Have three P tags with same name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69910/discussion-between-saifur-and-user1882624).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p")).getText()`. This will fetch the text from the `p` element.

Comment: Thanks Paul. If i have Multiple P Tags how should i handle It?

Comment: Are there also multiple radio buttons? In that case you could do `findElement("p input[value="3"]")` to select a specific one. And repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `p` tag is the parent tag of `input`, and the text 'Select from list' is a innerHTML/text of `p` tag, this below JAVA code might help (assuming you are using java):

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectedItem']/..")).getText();
```

This will retrieve the innerHTML/text of the `p` tag.